# Including a header-section to text-file?

Tags: file-header

I'm occasionally writing fanfiction-stories as plain-text files in emacs.  It would be great if emacs could add a "header-section" in the beginning of these documents, for example:

```
Title:
Author:
Chapter:
Series:
Rating:
Email:
```

Some fields - like Author and Email - could obviously be pre-filled...

---

How could something like this be accomplished in emacs?

What would be the best way of doing it?  Would it be an idea to make a new major-mode - based on text-mode - called fanfic?  Or perhaps a new minor-mode (called fanfic) to be used with the text-major-mode?  A major/minor-mode could perhaps also set-up a few other things - like fly-spell-mode, auto-fill-mode and a suitable page-width...

For completeness, I'd like to know how such a standard header could be added for:

- All new files created with emacs (just curious...)
- All files of a certain type - eg. all *.txt-files.  (I guess it could be bound to the file-type (*.txt) and/or the text-mode in emacs)
- Files created with a customized major/minor-mode

I've used emacs for a several years, but haven't really dived into customization or elisp much...  (why mess with perfection?  ;-)

Comment: Did you have a look at [Auto Insert](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoInsertMode), or [Yasnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/blob/master/README.mdown)?

Comment: [EmacsWiki Automatic File Headers](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutomaticFileHeaders)